# Gihub Fine-grained personal access tokens creation

Tags: github

What I am missing here?
How do you generate or request an access token?
I am enterprise client, and opted for the Fine-grained personal access tokens (beta).

Answer (score 0):

It's in `Settings > Developer settings > Personal access tokens > Fine-grained tokens`. You'll find a `Generate new token` button and, there, you'll be able to create your token with the permissions you require for you app. It's generated instantly and it will allow you to access your GitHub account from any app, specially if you have 2FA enabled.